# Expected value of the number of teams

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose there are 32 people, and we want to create a championship consisted of 16 teams (i.e., 2 people in each team). A system will pick these teams at random.

Further, suppose 4 of these 32 people are sick, and any team containing any sick person can't play in the championship.

Question is what is the expected number of teams remaining in the championship?

**My Approach**

I think we only have 3 possible outcomes here: 14 teams, 13 teams, and 12 teams based on how these sick people get distributed in the teams.

So the expected value would be $$ (P(14)*14) + (P(13)*13) + (P(12)*12) $$
where P(n) is the probability that n teams can participate in the championship.

**My Question**

I'm not sure if my intuition is correct or not. Also, I got stuck with finding P(n)

Comment: @user_194421 just edited my question. I think I'm confusing myself. There shouldn't be any denominator? not sure why you'd think the 3 should be P(14) + P(13) + P(12)

Comment: It would be there if the sum of the probabilities is not 1. But the sum is 1, so $P(14)+P(13)+P(12)=1$.

Comment: Are the teams different (as if they are numbered)? And are the positions in each team different (as if there's a leader)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$X_i = \begin{cases}
1  &\text{if team i includes at least one sick person} \\
0  &\text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$
for $i = 1,2,3 \dots ,16$.
Then
$$P(X_i = 0) = \frac{28}{32} \cdot \frac{27}{31}$$
so
$$E(X_i) = P(X_i = 1) = 1 - \frac{28}{32} \cdot \frac{27}{31}$$
for $i = 1,2,3, \dots ,16$. Therefore the expected number of teams which contain at least one sick person is
$$E \left( \sum_{i=1}^{16} X_i \right) =  \sum_{i=1}^{16} E(X_i) = 16 \left( 1 - \frac{28}{32} \cdot \frac{27}{31} \right) = 3.806$$

So the expected number of teams with no sick persons is
$$16 - 3.806 = \boxed{12.193}$$

Comment: There are only 4 sick people, by the above procedure, by summing up the expectation over 16 i's, you are including those times when the team might not have atleast one sick person and thus shall have an expectation equal to zero.  By linearity of expecation, you are multiplying 16 times the expectation of one i which could see itself repeated less than 16 times.

Comment: @SatishRamanathan I think what is bothering  you is that the $X_i$s are not independent.  But it is important to realize that $E(X+Y) = E(X)+E(Y)$ even if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: I can fully understand your line of reasoning that for linearity of expectation, independence is not necessary.  This indicator function line of reasoning is a valid approach often time used but difficult to understand as it is a bit of abstract not very outwardly explicit.  Don't bother, it kind of agrees with the other person's answer. but definitely the solution is elegant

Comment: @awkward This answer is equal to mine ($\frac{378}{31}$). But, are the teams different? And are the positions the same or different (like there is a leader)? I mean, suppose the sick people are A, B, C, D. Is AB, CD different from CD, AB and BA, CD? That's why I marked my answer "possibly incorrect."

Comment: @user_194421 Since the solution above does not use any combinatorics to count the teams, the question of whether the teams are distinct or not is irrelevant.  And you could also consider the positions within the team as distinct or not.  What matters is that the calculation for $P(X_i=0)$ is correct, and you could arrive at that formula either way: counting the positions as distinct or not.  It's a bit like poker hand probabilities: you may consider the order of the cards dealt or not, but you should get the same answer either way, just be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that there are $4$ sick people. Let's consider them "identical" for the purpose of this explanation. Let's distribute them into positions $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,...,a_{16},b_{16}$. whare the team $t_1$ consists of $a_1$ and $b_1$, the team $t_2$ consists of $a_2$ and $b_2$, etc.

There are $\binom{32}4=35960$ ways to distribute $4$ people into $32$ positions.

To find the number of ways to get $14$ teams participating, we choose $2$ teams (out of $16$) and put the sick people in both positions of each. There are $\binom{16}2=120$ possibilities.

To find the number of ways to get $13$ teams participating, we choose $3$ teams (out of $16$), then pick $1$ of those $3$ teams to contain two sick people, then for each of the $2$ remaining teams pick a position (out of $2$) in the team to contain a sick person. There are $\binom{16}3\cdot\binom31\cdot2^2=6720$ possibilities.

To find the number of ways to get $12$ teams participating, we choose $4$ teams (out of $16$), then pick a position (out of $2$) in each of those $4$ teams. There are $\binom{16}4\cdot2^4=29120$ possibilities.

A quick inspection verifies that the number of possibilities of the cases ($120,6720,29120$) add up to $35960$.

Now let's get the probabilities:

$$P(14)=\frac{120}{35960}\\
P(13)=\frac{6720}{35960}\\
P(12)=\frac{29120}{35960}$$

Substituting, the expected number of teams participating is

$$\begin{align}
&14\cdot\frac{120}{35960}+13\cdot\frac{6720}{35960}+12\cdot\frac{29120}{35960}\\
=&\frac{1680+87360+349440}{35960}\\
=&\frac{438480}{35960}\\
=&\frac{378}{31}\\
=&12\frac6{31}
\end{align}$$

### Hey, the sick people are different!

Consider that each possibility mentioned above can be turned to $4!=24$ "the sick people are different" (TSPAD) possibilities. It doesn't have any effect on the result. To see that, try multiplying each the nominators and denominators in the probability equations by $24$. It doesn't change the probability.